# AD User Array CSV search and analyze error

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, active-directory, export-to-csv

i want to search to an exported Active Directory list but i got one problem.

AD Files looks like this and its saved as CSV-File (I added a Header to the file)

```
CN=ARV-PRO7,OU=etc,OU=etc,DC=etc,DC=etc,DC=etc
CN=BLAPO86z,OU=etc,OU=etc,DC=etc,DC=etc,DC=etc
```

This is a example (there are 37 more entrys like ARV in the "where" is shoreted it for better view) of the Code im trying to run:

```
$Datei = Import-Csv "C:\FILESPATH\AD-list.csv"
$Datei | where {$_.CN -notmatch "ARV" -and $_.CN -notmatch "BBN"} | Out-GridView -Title "Site Info"
```

This shows me all the items with no ARV in it, thats what i want.
BUT it ignores also the items which looks like this:

```
CN=PR122ARVO7,OU=etc,OU=etc,DC=etc,DC=etc,DC=etc
```

Because ARV is in the name the item is not shown.
I need a way to check if the first 3 letter ARV than its okay and he can ignore it but i also need him to show me names with ARV in it to check the name rules. ( Department-PCNAME ) and not (BLABLA-PC-DEPARTMENT-NAME)

I Hope its clear what iam asking and what my problem is ^^

Comment: Does your CSV contain just the list of distinguished names? Or are there other fields? Please update your question with a *representative* CSV sample (including header(s)).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to ignore items starting with ARV. This should work (simplified, only where section is important here):

```
@{CN='ARV-PRO7'},
@{CN='BLAPO86z'},
@{CN='PR122ARVO7'} | where { !$_.CN.StartsWith('ARV') }
```